# Use Azure Blob storage for postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Azure blob storage has a maximum limit of 500TB. This is sufficient as I have (or will have) a lot of data.

I'd like to set up a server in Azure with PostGres installed, but I do not want to use the local SSD/HDD, because the size is limited... and the only way I can resize the disk (if I need to), is to shut down the VM and bang out some cryptic codes into PowerShell.

Is it possible to tell Postgres to use Azure blob storage?
If so, how can I do this?
If no, what options do I have? How can I make my HDD/SDD scale as I need more space, without any intervention on my part?

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Postgres SQL as a service option? It was announced recently - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/postgresql/.

Comment: It's totally impractical to run something like a RDBMS from an object store like S3 or Azure Blob. It'd run at a snail's pace if you could overcome the filesystem semantics issues, and good luck making it crash-safe.

Comment: The disks on your virtual machine are actually virtual disks stored as blobs with guaranteed IO, latency. That's why they are more expensive that "plain" blob storage. They *can* increase in size when needed

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly read/write from/to blob storage, via Postgres, as it expects a normal file system (with normal file I/O operations). To do that, there'd need to be modifications made to the Postgres storage system to accomplish such a thing.

The maximum storage footprint, from a normal OS file system perspective, would then be limited by the number of disks (which sit in page blobs) attached to your vm. Maximum 2 disks per core, maximum 4TB per disk (the larger disk sizes are new as of May 2017). That gives you a range of 8TB (single core) to 128TB (32 core). And you'd likely need to RAID those disks (unless Postgres supports a JBOD model).

As suggested by @Gaurav, you can also use Postgres-as-a-Service. Currently, while in Preview, that service has a limit of 1TB per database. Larger sizes will eventually be available.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't care how the disks are arranged FWIW. So long as you provide a file system with reasonably POSIX semantics that respects fsync(), it's happy. The underlying storage can be software RAID, hardware RAID, standalone disk, JBOD spanning, a SAN, hell, even NFS.

Comment: @CraigRinger - thanks for the clarification - great to know. Still, you'd need the storage to be attached disks (postgres will not be able to interact directly via blob storage REST API as it was never designed to do so). As such, you'd be able to format/mount/access them as you would any other disk, whether in Windows or Linux.

Comment: @CraigRinger blob storage in all providers doesn't even have a file system. The disks attached to VMs are essentially virtual disks stored as blobs *with special care* taken to ensure data replication and the throughput, IO characteristics you bought